# Run two functions on keyup change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do two things to the same input field.

```
$('#student').on('change', function () {
    checkSubjects();
});
$('#student').on('keyup', function () {
    checkBoolean();
});
```

Is there a better way to do this rather than having two separate functins?

Comment: you want to call different functions on different events? If so, then what you are doing is right.

Comment: You can do this without writing additional functions `<input id="student" onchange="checkSubjects();" onkeyup="checkBoolean();"/>`

Comment: @Becky Did you find the solution you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Tushar's answer is cleanest I can think of, but here's another way:

```
$("#student").on({
    change: function() {
        checkSubjects();
    },
    keyup: function() {
        checkBoolean();
    }
});
```

Here's a basic fiddle with the above in action (different events though - check the console as I'm logging messages when clicking or hovering): https://jsfiddle.net/hLu3vfLn/1/